# How to read a file delimited by \ in R?

Tags: r

I have a file as follows in a text file

```
a\b\c\d\f

399\I 2017\11\M\09

491\I 2017\01\Ma\161 

4\I 2014\01\M\16
```

In which `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and  `f` are the names of the variables.

Try to use without results

```
mv <- read.csv("p.txt", header=T, sep = "\")
```

Comment: `read.table("p.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\\")`

Comment: It is indeed so!

Comment: You should add that as a proper answer so this question can be marked as answered.